# If $\{u,v,w\}$ is LI , can the ${\rm span}(u,v)={\rm span}(v,w)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $u,v$, and $w$ are linearly independent, can the span of $u$ and $v$ equal the span of $v$ and $w$?

I think not necessarily, cause if there's an element in $w$ such that it is not a linear combination of $u$ and/or $v$, then span of $u$ and $v$ won't be equal to span of $v$ and $w$.

But I'm still confused

Comment: As a hint:  Suppose they were the same span.  Note that $\vec u$ is in in the span of $\vec v, \vec u$, so it must also be in the span of $\vec v, \vec w$.  Try to get a contradiction out of that.

Comment: To amplify the hint of @lulu, the contradiction you're looking for is a demonstration that, contrary to your assumption, $\{ \vec u, \vec v, \vec w \}$ is not in fact linearly independent; i.e., there's a non-trivial linear combination that's $\vec 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. As @lulu mentioned in the comment, assume for the sake of contradiction that $Span \{u, v\} = Span \{v, w\}$. Clearly, $u \in Span \{u, v\}$, since we can write $u = 1 u + 0 v$. Now, $u \in Span \{u, v\} \implies u \in Span \{v, w\}$. This means that there exists some $\alpha, \beta$ in the appropriate field such that $u = \alpha v + \beta w$. Note that we can rearrange this equation to $1u - \alpha v - \beta w = 0$, which implies that $\{u, v, w\}$ is not linearly independent.